# Why event open in server side events is looping?

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I took the basic example of a SSE and on the server I replaced {
`while (true)` with `for(int $x =0; $x<5; $x ++)`, even removed the for, but the client says 'Connection opened' every few seconds based on `evtSource.addEventListener('open', function(e) {},false);`. So if there are many clients I think the server will be overloaded, is this correct? How can this be fixed ?

Server code:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

$counter = rand(1, 10);
for(int $x =0; $x<5; $x ++){
//while (true) {
  // Every second, send a "ping" event.

  echo "event: ping\n";
  $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
  echo 'data: {"time": "' . $curDate . '"}';
  echo "\n\n";

  // Send a simple message at random intervals.

  $counter--;

  if (!$counter) {
    echo 'data: This is a message at time ' . $curDate . "\n\n";
    $counter = rand(1, 10);
  }

  ob_end_flush();
  flush();

  // Break the loop if the client aborted the connection (closed the page)

  if (connection_aborted()) break;

  sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Client code:

```
var evtSource = new EventSource('http://localhost/ssevent.php');
    
    evtSource.addEventListener('data', function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
    }, false);
    
    evtSource.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    // Connection was opened.
    console.log("Connection was opened.");
    }, false);
    
    evtSource.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
    // Connection was closed.
    evtSource.close();
    console.log("Error, connection was closed.");
    }
    }, false);
```

Comment: Please show the SSE / PHP code

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, I have edited the question with the code, thankyou.

Comment: EventSource may automatically reconnect when the connection is closed. This would mean that the connection is interrupted when it shouldn't be.
Try to debug the returns of connection_aborted

Comment: If the connection would close, why I am not getting the log "Error, connection was closed." ?

Comment: The default behaviour of an Event Source connection is, I believe, to attempt a re-connection immediately if the connection is dropped. You state `"the client says 'Connection opened' every few seconds"` - would that be every 5seconds as per the loop size x sleep time? If that is so that should help explain why an infinite loop is used - it will prevent this re-connect issue. However, as per the point regarding multiple concurrent connections  - it might well overload the server so perhaps a websocket might be more suitable?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius You are right, I misunderstood how this works and I rushed to replace the while loop, which indeed is preveinting the re-connections. I am sorry. Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved. I am trying to find something that I can use on a shared hosting, this is why I am not using websockets. Do you think using rest from time to time would be better than sse regarding the overloading ?